# Using Perl on Solaris, how do I import a C (.so) library?

Tags: c, perl, solaris

Is there any function to import a C library (`.so`) file in the Solaris operating system?

In Windows I can use [`Win32::API`](http://p3rl.org/Win32::API), how about Solaris?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XSLoader](http://perldoc.perl.org/XSLoader.html) looks to be the simple interface.

[DynaLoader](http://perldoc.perl.org/DynaLoader.html) looks to be the more complex interface.

But your modules have to be tailored to be imported into Perl; the [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swig) toolkit may be the best tool to marshal data between native C and native Perl.

Comment: The majority uses [XS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XS_%28Perl%29) instead of SWIG.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`C::DynaLib`](http://p3rl.org/C::DynaLib).

Answer (score -1):

If by import you mean just link against it, you can use `-l` followed by the base name of the library on the `cc`/`gcc`/ command line when linking. For example, to link to `libfoo.so`, use `-lfoo`.

If by import you mean dynamically load at runtime, lookup the `dlopen` and `dysym` functions.

Comment: Because ist subject is importing C libraries in Perl.